# Frailty Models: Gamma distributed frailty and Inverse Gaussian distributed frailty

Tags: distributions, frailty

In modelling of frailty using assumptions distributions of frailty are Gamma distributed frailty and Inverse Gaussian distributed frailty. Frailty is unobservable risk factor of mortality. How to fitting of these distributions of Gamma distributed frailty and Inverse Gaussian distributed frailty ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, frailty model is extended version of Proportional hazard model with random effect. There are various approach to fit frailty model for time-to-event data. Your question is not specific. Please ask specific question. By the way, you can follow this http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00985760